# Civimail stats being thrown off

Tags: civimail, civireport

Is anyone else seeing mailing stats being completely thrown out by what I assume is a security product? We are routinely seeing some. .ac.uk and .ie addresses which record a click and a separate open for every single link in a mailing. I am assuming that some mail scanning software is scanning every link, for every separate recipient on an email domain, every time, before delivering the email to the recipient.

We sent a recent mailing that appeared to have 3100 clicks. After removing all duplicates, the figure remaining was 135!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can indeed happen if the recipient uses some kind of screening / security application that "checks" links contained in emails (we have seen that with some MS products as well). Afaik there is nothing in CiviCRM "out of the box" to prevent that. You could of course build some script / query etc. that identifies and deletes those but it would probably become a bit fuzzy.